# Spring startup error: NoSuchMethodError in EnableWebMvcConfiguration.addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(Ljava/util/List)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have encountered a problem. After adding AOP to an older Spring Boot version, the service cannot run normally. The exception information is as follows. I've tried to find a solution, but haven't found one thus far.

Here's the error:

````
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.7.RELEASE)
05-25 10:00:54.060 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
05-25 10:00:54.066 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
05-25 10:00:54.066 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'springSessionRepositoryFilter' to: [/*]
05-25 10:00:54.066 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
05-25 10:00:54.066 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
05-25 10:00:54.066 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
05-25 10:00:55.962 [main] WARN  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'handlerExceptionResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(Ljava/util/List;)V
05-25 10:00:55.968 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
05-25 10:00:55.979 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
05-25 10:00:55.983 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'handlerExceptionResolver' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(Ljava/util/List;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1187) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1176) [spring-boot-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sunshine.SpringbootApplication.main(SpringbootApplication.java:29) [classes/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExceptionResolver]: Factory method 'handlerExceptionResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(Ljava/util/List;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.addDefaultHandlerExceptionResolvers(Ljava/util/List;)V
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.configureHandlerExceptionResolvers(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:429) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.handlerExceptionResolver(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:947) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b77399b8.CGLIB$handlerExceptionResolver$27(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b77399b8$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d5a9eefc.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b77399b8.handlerExceptionResolver(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.7.RELEASE.jar:1.4.7.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_321]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_321]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_321]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_321]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 19 more```
````

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` means a version mismatch; with Boot, this means you're overriding some managed version, and inspecting the verions of `spring-*` should show you which. This version is _outrageously_ obsolete, and you should at a minimum upgrade to 1.5.22.

Comment: Could post your dependencies from `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`?

Comment: Sorry, I can only provide part of the code due to word limit  `<properties>
 <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 <spring.version>4.3.12.RELEASE</spring.version>
 <spring.security.version>4.3.12.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
 <spring.cloud.config.version>1.3.1.RELEASE</spring.cloud.config.version>
 <spring.cloud.version>1.1.6.RELEASE</spring.cloud.version>
  </properties>`

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this situation, i dnot know if it is the same as you,
if you write a class to case some kind of exceptoin,Maybe you should give a param in that method! like :

```
public type methodName(Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

that (Exception e) do you write that?

and that @ExceptionHandler can not have same class like :

```
@ExceptionHandler(A.class)
public type handleException(SomeExceptionAA e) {
...
}
....
@ExceptionHandler(A.class)
public type handleException(SomeExceptionAB e) {
...
}
```

like this is wrong! there is two @ExceptionHandler case A.class!

Up there is the two situations i haveencountered ,hope that can help you!

Comment: 感谢你的回答，我看了下我的项目代码并未发现存在这样的问题，我是在尝试用config配置类进行配置文件注入时产生的异常